# issue in nesting timeline : GreenSock for javascript

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am nesting timeline.

code is like:

```
timeLine.to(obj1,1.2,{css:{display:"block"}})  

nestedTimeline1 = new TimelineMax({repeat:1});

// initially obj2 is with opacity :0

nestedTimeline1.append(TweenLite.to(obj2,1.4,{css:{opacity:1,left:187,bottom:108}}))
nestedTimeline1.append(TweenLite.to(obj2,.5,{css:{opacity:0}}),-.8)

timeLine.append(nestedTimeline1);
```

when i do:

```
timeLine.totalProgress(0);
```

my animation will start from first. But the issues is obj2 opacity will not be reset to 0.

i am not able to understand why this issue is coming?

any solution will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

Lets start with the first line.

You cannot animate to `display:block` - There's no numerical value to animate. You can animate from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` just fine.

Now, lets think about the next problem.
You're attempting to animate `opacity` to `1` over `1.4` seconds.
Your next tween animates the same object from whatever to `0` over `0.5` seconds, with an offset of `-0.8` seconds.

I'm not sure if you see the error here, but lets break it down in to a visual representation.

```
-------------------------------------------------- <-- Tween 1
                           ---------------         <-- Tween 2
```

You see, Tween 2 finishes *before* Tween 1, since you pushed it back in the timeline `0.8` seconds and it only runs for `0.5` seconds. So Tween 1 now has that final `0.3` seconds to animate back to `opacity:1`

Also as a side note, you can use the convenience methods rather than `.append(TweenLite...`
`nestedTimeline1.to(...)` does the same thing.